# writing a script using killproc

Tags: bash, kill

Okay, I have an assignment and I am very very new to Unix. Here is what I am trying to do: I wrote a script to kill a running process. I have to use the command killproc. I just don't know where to put it or how. Every time I try to use killproc when I run the script I get an error: command not found

```
killproc '[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*'

process=$(ps | grep "$@")

while [[ $process ]] ; do

pid=$(echo $process | cut -d' ' -f 1)
name=$(echo $process | cut -d' ' -f 4)

echo -e "PID: $pid \t Name: $name"
echo -n "Would you like to kill $name [yes/no]"

read word < /dev/tty

kill $pid

fi

process=$(ps | grep "$process")

done
```

Comment: hmmm....."have to use killproc"  ... is this a homework assignment?

Comment: it is. I don't know much about Unix but I cant seem to find much about killproc either :/

Comment: Wifil, I don't find a program of that name on my PCs; could it be that the assignment says "write a program **called** 'killproc'" and not "write a program that is **calling**  [a program named] 'killproc'"?

Comment: implement an interactive script that will selectively kill processes on the system.
The format of the command is: killproc process_pattern

where process_pattern is the name of the process to remove. Note that when testing with a regular expression, the process_pattern may need to be enclosed in quotes to protect it from the shell. The script must do the following:

Use the ps command to gather information on appropriate processes. 
For each instance of a process with that name, ask user if they would like to remove it.

Comment: Wifil, yes, "The format [i.e. call synopsis] of the command [**that you have to write**] is: `killproc process_pattern` where [...]".

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the task is to write a program (a shell script) `killproc`.

What you have to do with your above script is; 1) remove the first line of the code, 2) add a first line `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/bash`, depending on where your bash is located, 3) save the resulting program with the name `killproc`, and 4) change permissions to make the script executable `chmod +x killproc` (and be sure the command will be found through your PATH setting).

Then it should be possible to call your program `killproc 'some_pattern'`.

(Note that there are issues with your code, but as it's an assignment you should figure that out yourself.)